# Updating JPanel contents through ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I have a `JPanel` that displays a group of `JLabels` which are all computed and printed on the fly inside of a method. The contents of the labels are held in an `ArrayList`

In another method more objects are added to the `ArrayList` through an action listener as such:

```
class listener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){

            String name = myTextArea.getText();

            Object temp = new Object(name);
            myList.add(temp);
            panel = createPanel();
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
            card.show(contentsPanel, "panel");
    }
}
```

`createPanel()` is what takes the `ArrayList` and makes a display of it.

This, of course, is a bit of an abstraction, but the idea remains. 
The problem comes in when I try to update the contents and look of the panel with `.revalidate()` and `.repaint()`. I know the objects are in the ArrayList as I have tested it, but the panel doesn't redraw itself correctly.

Any suggestions? If necessary I can provide additional information or code.

As per request I will include the code. I can't attach the whole thing, due to size, but here is the method it references:

```
    private JPanel createPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(myList.size(), 1));
    panel.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));

    for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
        JLabel temp = new JLabel(myList.get(i).toString());
        panel.add(temp);
    }

    return panel;       
}
```

Comment: plz provide that additional information of code.. perhaps, a running copy i could copy paste and run and see..

Comment: You're not adding the panel to a parent component in the code segment you're showing.

Comment: You are creating a new panel and not replace the old one. You should not recreate it in the first place.

Comment: The 'panel' that is referenced is a class object. As far as I can tell, it should reference that. I updated the question to include the method that creates the panel.

Comment: Changing the reference does NOT update the panel that is displayed on the GUI. You still need to add the panel to the GUI as has been suggested twice. Or another approach is to remove all the components from the existing panel and that add the new components to the panel. Then you don't have to add the panel back to the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have added the newly create `JPanel` anywhere.

(It also looks like you are assigning the field `panel` inside both `createPanel` and `actionPerformed`. And also have a class called `Object` - using any name already used by `java.lang` is a bad idea.)

Comment: I changed the names of the variables for the example as they wouldn't make sense out of context. But this solution works, thank you.